# How to use .skin file present in a folder under Theme folder?

Tags: asp.net, themes, skin, app-themes

friends...
I want to use skin file "Black.skin" which is present in a folder "Skins" under theme's folder "Black_Theme" as shown folder structure in below fig.

[image: Project Folder Structure]

> 

In .aspx page, I am using

```
<%@ Page StylesheetTheme="Black_Theme"
```

and in body, I am using skin file as

```
 <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click Me" SkinID="yellow" />
```

But When I run and check output, page is rendered as no skin applied.
So, some how skin file is not applied.
When I move skin file to theme's folder, it works as expected.
So, I need to give reference of skin file in a folder under theme's folder.

How to use .skin file present in a folder under Theme folder ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set Value of theme Properties in Pages tag in Web.Config File 
like < pages theme="default" />

Comment: I tried that but skin file is not in theme folder. skin file is inside Skins folder under theme folder. That's why it is not working.